Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fromDate')
I am getting this error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fromDate'), when I try to get the expiry time for the otp I getting from Twilio. So I am using firebase function for my backend and I am successfully getting an OTP but I am getting that error for reasons unknown to me.
This is my code below in "functions/src/index.ts" file.
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import twilio from "twilio";
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";
// import {getFirestore, Timestamp} from "firebase-admin/firestore";

dotenv.config();
admin.initializeApp();

// const firestore = getFirestore();

const twilioClient = twilio(
  process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID,
  process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN
);

const generateOtp = (): string => {
  return Math.floor(100000 + Math.random() * 900000).toString();
};

// Send OTP via SMS
export const sendOtpSms = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const {phoneNumber} = req.body;

  if (!phoneNumber) {
    res.status(400).json({error: "Phone number is required"});
    return;
  }

  const otp = generateOtp();

  try {
    await twilioClient.messages.create({
      body: `Your OTP is ${otp}`,
      from: process.env.TWILIO_PHONE,
      to: phoneNumber,
    });

    if (typeof admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate === "function") {
      const expiresAt = admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(
        new Date(Date.now() + 5 * 60000)
      );
      await admin.firestore().collection("otps").doc(phoneNumber).set({
        otp,
        expiresAt,
      });
      console.log(`Generated OTP: ${otp}, Expires At: ${expiresAt.toDate()}`);
    } else {
      console.log(`Generated OTP: ${otp}`);
      res.status(500).json({error: "fromDate is not available"});
      return;
    }

    res.status(200).json({message: "OTP sent successfully"});
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error sending OTP:", error);
    res.status(500).json({error: "Failed to send OTP"});
  }
});

// Verify Otp
export const verifyOtp = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const {phoneNumber, otp} = req.body;

  if (!phoneNumber || !otp) {
    res.status(400).json({error: "Phone number and OTP are required"});
    return;
  }

  try {
    const otpDoc = await admin
      .firestore()
      .collection("otps")
      .doc(phoneNumber)
      .get();
    if (!otpDoc.exists) {
      res.status(404).json({error: "OTP not found"});
      return;
    }

    const otpData = otpDoc.data();

    if (!otpData || !otpData.expiresAt) {
      res.status(400).json({error: "OTP data is incomplete"});
      return;
    }

    const isExpired = otpData?.expiresAt.toDate() < new Date();

    if (isExpired) {
      res.status(400).json({error: "OTP has expired"});
      return;
    }

    if (otp !== otpData?.otp) {
      res.status(400).json({error: "Invalid OTP"});
      return;
    }

    res.status(200).json({message: "OTP verified successfully"});
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error verifying OTP:", error);
    res.status(500).json({error: "Failed to verify OTP"});
  }
});

I have checked if it is undefined, I have done all I can but I am not getting any solution.
I will be glad to get a reply on how to sort this out because it is getting frustrating at this point. I have tried all I can, search online and also used chatGPT and Google Gemini but I could not get a solution.

The error means that admin.firestore.Timestamp is undefined. Where are you checking that?

You can use conditional chaining: if (typeof admin.firestore.Timestamp?.fromDate === 'function')

I did that before and it still did not work, thank you
